# Convert SVG to STL

Tags: svg, printing, 3d, stl-format

I've been working with SVG ascii format and my drawings are all composed of a path of x,y coordinates, like:

```
0,240.74296894669533
9.655468761920929,240.39843770861626
19.157812505960464,239.9007814526558
```

Now I am trying to figure it out how to put it in stl facets format. I've tried a few converters and the results don't make too much sense for me right now.

For instance, a list of 80 path coordinates (which is not much) is generating a 932 facets list.

I've read some stl format articles but they tend to be too much theoretical. Any hints on this?

Suppose I have an straight line, with only 2 coordinates. How could they be represented by facets?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try convert SVG to STL by using this online tool
http://svg2stl.com/

Comment: Of course! But... I'm looking for some kind of plugin... or internal module to attach to another software. I wonder how to get these x/y coordinates and create the STL triangles

Comment: Thanks wilix! I will take a look!